# Django - why path is mentioned in different format for admin compared to our app

Tags: django

I am new to django , in `urls.py` why do we mention the path to our app as

`path('appname/', include(appname.urls))`

whereas for admin its mentioned as below

`path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll find is that you've got the following import into the urls;

`from django.contrib import admin`

Following that `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` references the urls module from the imported `admin`.

Whereas when you use `include` you provide a string and then django will figure out the importing for you. Otherwise you'd have to import each module with URLs which you want to load.